# Mockito not mocking function from controller in test

Tags: java, testing, mockito, micronaut

I am trying to mock a method my controller calls as shown:

```
@Post(value = "/blah", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Transactional
    public HttpResponse<Object> createBlah(HttpHeaders httpHeaders,
            @Body @Valid CreateBlahRequest createBlahRequest) {
        HttpResponse<Object> createBlahResponse;

        (...)
        createBlahService(...) // what i am trying to mock

        return HttpUtils.getResponse(HttpStatus.CREATED, createBlahResponse.body());
    }
```

And in my test I am testing as shown:

```
    @Mock
    public BlahController blahController;

    public HttpResponse<Object> resp = HttpResponse.created((Object) new AccountResponse()).status(HttpStatus.OK);

    @BeforeAll
    public void configureAppContext() {
        Application.APPLICATION_CONTEXT = applicationContext;
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

@Test
    void createBlah(){

        MutableHttpRequest<CreateBlahRequest> request = HttpRequest
                .POST("/blah", createBlahRequest)
                .header("requestId", "1");

        when(blahController.createBlah(eq(request.getHeaders()), eq(createBlahRequest))).thenReturn(resp);

        HttpResponse<CreateBlahRequest> blahRes = client.toBlocking().exchange(request, CreateBlahRequest.class);

    }
```

However, when the client makes the call to the controller, it doesn't seem to get matched by the (when) that is inside of my test, it continues to run as is. If anyone could please give some advice on this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You haven't show us enough code to work out the answer. I can't see how `client` is instantiated in the test, and I can't see how createBlah is called (from I assume in the client somewhere)

Comment: client is just an RxHttpClient, and createBlah is called from the client calling the controller with the specific path that matches to createBlah

Comment: and `createBlahRequest` ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I am not sure what your intent was but it looks like what you are trying to do is leave the real controller out of it altogether in which case your test wouldn't be testing any of your code aside from the code in the test itself.  Is that your intent?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown the intent was to test that the endpoint call of the controller works. I wanted to mock the behavior of a method in it because it calls an external API which I wanted to mock. I just wanted to test endpoint hitting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who sees this, I had to inject the class that the method calls.
In the controller it calls another service class so I mocked it like so:

```
@Inject
public BlahService BlahService;

@MockBean(BlahService.class)
public BlahService blahService(){
    return Mockito.mock(BlahService.class);
}
```

and it worked fine.

Comment: This definitely makes more sense than the original attempt described in the question.  The original attempt was attempting to mock the controller in which case you would't be testing any thing other than the mock itself.

Comment: sure sorry for the confusion, I protected too much of the source code will make edits to make it more clear for the next readers

Answer (score -1):

[Sample Mockito Example for API's](https://github.com/naveenkulkarni029/products-api)